# Android DynamoDB @DynamoDBTable

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

I'm setting up basic app to upload data to DynamoDB. I was following aws tutorial. But I have an error which should not happen. Here's my code:

This is the class for my item to upload:

```
package com.plexinc.easyorder;

import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBTable;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName="Bars")
public class Bar {
    private String BarID;
    private String PlaceName;
    private String Address;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="BarID")
    public String getBarID(){
        return BarID;
    }

    public void setBarID(String BarID){
        this.BarID = BarID;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "PlaceName")
    public String getPlaceName(){
        return PlaceName;
    }

    public void setPlaceName(String Name) {
        this.PlaceName = Name;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Address")
    public String getAddress(){
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.Address = Address;
    }
}
```

And here is the call to dynamoDB:

```
Bar testBar = new Bar();
testBar.setAddress("thisisAddress 123123");
testBar.setPlaceName("Meltdown");
testBar.setBarID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

new android.os.AsyncTask<Bar, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bar... toSave) {
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(MainActivity.client);
        mapper.save(toSave);
        return null;
    }
}.execute(testBar);
```

When I try to executer the code I get the error: 
 class [Lcom.plexinc.easyorder.Bar; must be annotated with interface com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBTable

I checked the syntax on @DynamoDBTable but it is exactly the same as the one in the tutorial. I don't understand and this is certainly a stupid mistake but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for the answers

Comment: The Bar class looks fine. I have tested the Bar class with Java program. It works fine. Please check the AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks for checking the class. I modified my Task to create the DynamoDB client and mapper inside (I only created mapper inside) as I saw other people do on internet. However it does not solve the problem. It is the exact copy of the one in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: You have to create the item (in my case the object Bar) **inside** the async task (in the doInBackground) and not outside.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. My problem exactly.